# Date and Time Calculation in Sharepoint Excluding Weekends and displayed in minutes

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date-time

[image]

The code below is working well to calculate the time between two dates and excluding weekends. However, I would like to modify it to just return the number of minutes in number format so I can do some averages on that column.

[image]

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Quote Start Time]),ISBLANK([Quote Complete Time])),"",IF(AND((WEEKDAY([Quote Complete Time],2))<(WEEKDAY([Quote Start Time],2)),((WEEKDAY([Quote Start Time],2))-(WEEKDAY([Quote Complete Time],2)))>1),(((DATEDIF([Quote Start Time],[Quote Complete Time],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Quote Start Time],[Quote Complete Time],"D"))/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF([Quote Start Time],[Quote Complete Time],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Quote Start Time],[Quote Complete Time],"D"))/7,1)*2)))&" days, "&TEXT(MOD([Quote Complete Time]-[Quote Start Time],1),"hh "" hrs,"" mm "" mins"""))
```

The second answer is working great to show minutes but it is off by one minute. Any ideas on that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the *1440 to *1448 and that achieved the desired results!

Comment: Hi Shannon Kearney. I'm glad to hear that your problem has been solved. If the answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the below Formula:**

```
=(IF(OR(ISBLANK([Quote Start Time]),ISBLANK([Quote Complete Time])),"",IF(AND((WEEKDAY([Quote Complete Time],2))<(WEEKDAY([Quote Start Time],2)),((WEEKDAY([Quote Start Time],2))-(WEEKDAY([Quote Complete Time],2)))>1),(((DATEDIF([Quote Start Time],[Quote Complete Time],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Quote Start Time],[Quote Complete Time],"D"))/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF([Quote Start Time],[Quote Complete Time],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Quote Start Time],[Quote Complete Time],"D"))/7,1)*2)))))*1440+INT(MOD([Quote Complete Time]-[Quote Start Time],1)*1440)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm except it appears to be off by a minute. Any ideas about that?